# how to populate a html table inside a dynamically loaded DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a DIV container inside a HTML page where I am dynamically loading other HTML pages using jquery.load() function . On one of the pages i need to populate a table from the database just after/before that page loads. How do I call a javascript function that executes just after that DIV is loaded with the page.

this is the dynamically loaded "headquarters.html" page:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10"  >
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tbl_hqlist">
                <tr>
                    <th> HQ Code</th>
                    <th> Headquarter Name</th>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

i am loading that page using jquery.load() function like below:

```
function fn_headquarters(){
    $('#bodyContent').load("../html/headquarters.html");
    headquarterManagement();
    return;
 }

function headquarterManagement(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"../bin/manage_hq.php",
            data:{  'procAction': 1},
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(proc_msg){

       //   get data and populate the table using jquery.each() & jquery.append() functions

            },
            error: function(xhr){
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        })
        return;
 }
```

this code fails to update "tbl_hqlist".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `load()` uses AJAX and is therefore asynchronous, lucky for you, it provides a callback parameter. Adjust like so...

```
function fn_headquarters(){
    $('#bodyContent').load("../html/headquarters.html", function(){
        headquarterManagement();
    });
    return;
 }
```

By doing this, you will make sure the element actually exists before populating it.

---

?Bonus: This will create table markup from json data:

```
function makeTableFromArray(arrayOfData){
    var html_buffer = [];
    html_buffer.push("<table><thead><tr>");
    var headerData = arrayOfData[0];
    for(var p in headerData)
        if(headerData.hasOwnProperty(p))
            html_buffer.push("<th>"+p+"</th>");
    html_buffer.push("</tr></thead><tbody>");
    for(var i=0; i<arrayOfData.length; i++){
         html_buffer.push("<tr>");
         for(var p in arrayOfData[i])
             if(arrayOfData[i].hasOwnProperty(p))
                 html_buffer.push("<td>"+arrayOfData[i][p]+"</td>");
         html_buffer.push("</tr>");
    }
    html_buffer.push("</table>");
    return html_buffer.join("");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sbctwdLc/